interpretation regression metrics
I ran a dataset with random forest model. The results are as follows. Why MSE is extremely high, but r2 square shows an accuracy of about 83-84%? Is this a normal occurrence and related to the dataset or does it indicate a problem?

Test set evaluation:
_____________________________________
MAE: 226.77896888406613
MSE: 72766.53733725657
RMSE: 269.752733697467
Median 246.18115105873255
Max_error 594.841276285923
R2 Square 0.8305763821081303
__________________________________
Train set evaluation:
_____________________________________
MAE: 240.49495327574056
MSE: 76745.88393140837
RMSE: 277.0304747341136
Median 239.40881247361523
Max_error 629.2701141138295
R2 Square 0.8409408669637992


$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right) =
1-\left(\dfrac{
N\times MSE
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$
If the MSE is high yet the $R^2$ is also high, it means that the denominator term must be really high. In fact, we can calculate exactly what it is.
$$
1 - R^2 = \left(\dfrac{
N\times MSE
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)\\
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2 = \dfrac{N\times MSE}{1 - R^2}
$$
When you do the calculation, does this last equality check out? If so, then everything is fine. If it doesn't, then you made a mistake somewhere, either in checking this or earlier in your work.
$R^2$ is useful in that it makes you compare to a benchmark model that always predicts the mean, regardless of feature values, reasonably thought of as a "must-beat" level of performance. If you can't beat the "must-beat" level of performance, there is a problem. However, $R^2$ is more complicated than seeing that you get $R^2 = 0.83$ so that is like a solid $\text{B}$ in school. For that matter, so is classification accuracy. I get into this here, and that calculation has the same caveats as the earlier link has for the usual $R^2$.

In general I wouldn't focus too much on too many accuracy KPIs but rather stick to one that is fitting you problem and focus on tuning for that.
Looking only at your numbers without knowing your dataset doesn't really work though. But maybe let me give you a couple of pointers on how to do the evaluation:

Having your MSE being "high" means nothing without knowing the range your target variable is at. Example: maybe you are predicting something that has a range of 10000. Then having an MSE of 72766 (or rather an RMSE of 246) is totally acceptable. If your range is more in the 1 to 600 (which your Median might suggest) then having such an RMSE might be problematic

a large r2 doesn't mean you have an accuracy of 84%. r2 is "just" telling you that you have a sort of high variation in your prediction and your features. Having a high r2 is not necessarily telling you, that your prediction or model are "good"

looking at how your train and test set are different I would say in terms of generalisation your model might be doing ok though. That there is a slight difference with your training set being worse is to be expected in most cases. But again I'd be careful here without doing a validation test for example as well

in general during model evaluation look at 1-2 accuracy kpis that are the "correct" ones for your business problem and from there do some deep dive into your actual predictions. Where are they good? Where are they bad? Can you derive more information that might result in additional features from that?


